# Webpack with multiple roots and dynamic requires

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have webpack configured with two roots:

```
resolve: {
  root: [ path.resolve('./src/siteName'), path.resolve('./src/common') ]
},
```

Module resolve works perfectly when I require a module by name `require('moduleName')`. It looks in `siteName` folder and if it doesn't find the module there it looks in `common` folder.

When I try to require a module dynamically `require('Pages/' + pageModuleName)`, webpack adds all files from `siteName/Pages` to the bundle but it ignores files in `common/Pages` folder.

I looked into `require.context` but it doesn't really solve my problem as it ends up including **all** the files from both folders.

```
var req = require.context('../', true, /\/(siteName|common)\/Pages/);
var page = req(pageModuleName);
```

---

To sum up, given a file structure like the following:

```
common/Pages/PageA.js
common/Pages/PageB.js
siteName/Pages/PageA.js
```

When I do something like

```
require('Pages/' + pageModuleName);
```

Is it possible for webpack to be configured in a way that will add **just**

```
siteName/Pages/PageA.js
common/Pages/PageB.js
```

to the bundle and "ignore"

```
common/Pages/PageA.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late but still this problem can be actual today :)

I was trying to find the answer myself. I guess there is no "pretty" solution but I can offer an "ugly" one that just works. And yes, you have to explicitly list all physical paths you want to use with `require.context`, because Webpack resolves each path only once and does not do it on each potential module. So if it finds a folder it just stops searching (obviously).

```
function requireAll(req, cb) {
    // store moduleName => module mappings to prevent overriding
    let modules = {};
    if (!Array.isArray(req)) req = [req];
    // go trough each require.context
    for (let reqItem of req) {
        // go through each module
        for (let name of reqItem.keys()) {
            // skip module if it is already required
            if (modules.hasOwnProperty(name)) continue;
            // require module
            let module = reqItem(name);
            if (module.default) module = module.default;
            // callback
            if (cb) cb(module, name);
            // memorize module
            modules[name] = module;
        }
    }
    return modules;
}

requireAll([
    // require pririty is as follows
    require.context('path1/', true),
    require.context('path2/', true)
], (module, name) => {
    // whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to achieve.

When you

```
resolve: {
  root: [ path.resolve('./src/siteName'), path.resolve('./src/common') ]
},
```

It effectively teels webpack to use `./src/siteName/` and `./src/common` as root. So if you have `/pages` in both directories, you end up have duplicate paths.

```
  //what you want                   // what webpack see
siteName/pages/PageA.js               pages/PageA.js
siteName/pages/PageB.js        =>     pages/PageB.js
common/pages/PageA.js                 pages/PageA.js
common/pages/PageB.js                 pages/PageB.js
```

So you need to set it to

```
resolve: {
  root: [ path.resolve('./src') ]
},
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a little bit? I'm not looking to create two bundles and I can't see how this can work with two configs. My entry point is located in the `common` folder and that's actually the file/router with the dynamic `require`.

Comment: @JohnNikolakis oops.. I misunderstood. but I don't think what you are trying to do can be achieved. you might want to consider changing your routes naming, or do the require from within the file and use absolute path. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/472